# Delete part of audio

Tags: audio, editing, sound-editing

How can I delete part of an audio file while there would be no distortion in mixing point of two other parts? Let's say two other parts (after and before deleted part) are mixed together smartly so it's not possible to recognize that something between them is missing. Maybe a smart filter that mix two remaining part in a place which both have same frequency.

I currently use Adobe Audition and I couldn't find anything to do this. If audition can't do this, suggestion on other apps that maybe can do this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

This is an ordinary function of any audio editor -- it's what editing is. I don't know of a specific tool within your program to do this, or what specific challenges you see. But unless there are odd or unusual circumstances, it's a simple matter for an experienced operator to join two segments.

In a program like Audacity (free), you might place the two segments on different tracks, with appropriate spacing, and make a short dissolve between the tracks -- fade the first track out while fading the second one in. But without access to the actual sound, it's hard to be any more specific.

Comment: I use Adobe Audition and for sure it's much more powerful. And for audio consider a mp3 song that I want to remove vocal parts. I don't want to fade in and fade out the two parts, instead find similar area near two cutting part and rejoin them at that points.

Comment: I suggested a dissolve (crossfade), not a fade out followed by a fade in, as a way of masking or smoothing any small differences between the segments. From other replies it looks like you're talking about music, and want a tool that will help you line up beats, is that correct? We have to guess because you're giving us limited info.

Comment: Yes, it's a song that I want to cut the parts that have vocal. I don't know about crossfade in audition.

Comment: +1 Totally agree - there are just too many issues at stake to expect software to be able to handle this - it's a manual edit and if it's music then make sure you cut on zero crosses and the bit you're sticking to it is also cut on a zero cross and heading in the same direction either positive or negative. Make sure it aligns with a bar - sometimes you can cut on half a bar but it's a 2 minute thing for someone with experience.

Answer (score 1):

Normally you cut on a break in the sound.  If not, as long as the sound on the other end of both is roughly the same, you could try a cross fade.  Otherwise, you are pretty much out of luck.

Sounds are very complex things for the most part and if we're very good at picking out if they don't line up right.  Almost any sudden change is going to be noticeable to an attentive listener.

Comment: Cross fade are recognizable as well. What I want is editor comes back from start point of deleted part as well as it goes forward from the end point of deleted part and find points that matches best, and suggest them. as it's one song with one theme I think there must be such points. When one of them is selected the extra parts are removed as well.

Comment: @Ali - I understand the limitations of cross fading.  What I'm saying is it is the best you can possibly hope for.  What it sounds like you are trying to do is technically impossible due to the level of variability in audio signals unless you are talking about solely electronically produced and digitally sampled audio.  No two notes being sung by the same person or different moments of an analog instrument being played are similar enough to cut mid-sound without a noticeable change to an attentive listener.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to view the wav form of the track in audition, zoom in so it's obvious and cut it together manually. I don't believe there is a program or plugin that automatically finds two different points that would cut together well. Hopefully if you zoom in close enough, it's easy to see two sets of wav forms in similar shapes or at similar levels to cut together.

Comment: Waveform actually shows the volume level not the frequency, so even the volume is preserved at the cut point but the output is changed suddenly.